# How to use Atom as an IDE

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I searched but the answers I found were not helpful.

I installed Atom and, along with it, MinGW, and configured the system variables.

When I test Atom with a single C++ file it works  fine, but because I have to use Classes and thus create .h and .cpp files, it seems like it doesn't compile the files, only the main, which leads to errors.

How can I configure Atom  to compile all files, not just the main?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create bigger projects with C++ you can use a custom script using shell or bat, with a compiler like MinGW and execute it from the command line. Or 
use a build tool like [`cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html)  with the [build_cmake](https://atom.io/packages/build-cmake) Atom plugin.